# Does my workout time have to be consistent?

Tags: workout

How important is it to have a consistent workout time?

If I workout one day at 6am, the next day at 8pm and then the next day at 3pm for example, will this have a negative impact or a negligible impact?

I'm asking in general, although the types of exercises I am doing are pushups, situps and various dumbbell exercises for strength building.

Comment: I think the main issue I see is whether or not your muscles have recovered and what detriment there might be if they have not.  I doubt having a consistent schedule makes much difference otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Something to consider for others who might read this post:  If you are a runner and training to run a long race (marathon or the sort) and you know the race will be in the morning, it might make sense to do a lot of runs in the morning.  Ideally you run about the same time you race for two reasons:  1) Getting used to running that time of day can be important.  It'll be good to get your body/mind used to running hard in the AM if you are not used to it.  2) Bathroom habits can be training/learned.  If you get up and run each day at the same time you can eventually 'learn' to go to the bathroom before your run.  Could save you a few minutes race day if you have already taken a 'pit stop' before the race is underway.

This can also be applied to multi-day running.  If you will race through the night, it will be wise to train your body (and know what it feels like) to run at 'weird hours'.

Otherwise I agree with the above, as long as you have good time for recovery, anytime will suffice for training.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are allowing time for recovery, it shouldn't matter for general fitness. Make sure you are eating right and your sleep is good and you should be all set

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think it matters, the most important aspect is that making sure you actually are able to fit in your workout which is what you seem to be doing! As the others have posted above, maybe just consider recovery between sessions. But other than that, keep up the good work!